# Синтаксис инициализации const членов класса

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор

Есть класс

```
class object
{
  public: object();
  private: const double mass;
};
```

Инициализация `const double mass` в конструкторе отрабатывает только так:

```
object::object(): mass(1) { }
```

Почему не проходит такой вариант?

```
object::object() { 
   this->mass = 1;
}
```

И как в таком случае инициализировать `const` члены класса, которые должны предварительно высчитываться относительно входных параметров конструктора?

Какие варианты в C++ удобны для объявления/инициализации const членов класса?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Когда выполняется тело конструктора, то все члены данных объекта уже созданы.
Поэтому в этом конструкторе

```
object::object() { 
   this->mass = 1;
}
```

в предложении

```
   this->mass = 1;
```

применяется оператор присваивания, который нельзя использовать с константными объектами.

Если вам нужно определить значение константного члена данных на основе некоторых вычислений, то в качестве инициализатора используйте некоторую, например, статическую функцию - член класса.

```
object::object( some_argument ): mass( some_function( some_argument ) ) { }
```

Аргументами функции не обязательно должны быть аргументы конструктора. Можно использовать статические члены данных класса, не статически члены данных, которые уже были инициализированы в списке инициализации (лги в объявлении класса должны предшествовать,  или объекты, которые находятся в области видимости определения конструктора.

Ниже показан пример

```
#include <iostream>

class Object
{
public: 
    Object( double x ) : x ( 2 * x ), mass( init( this->x ) )
    {
    }

    double get_mass() const { return mass; }

private: 
    double x;
    const double mass;
    static double init( double x )
    {
        return x < 0 ? -x / 2 : x; 
    }
};  

int main() 
{
    Object obj( 10 );

    std::cout << obj.get_mass() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Почему для инициализации обязательна static функция класса? Разве обычная функция класса не будет в области видимости конструктора? Или дело не в этом?

Comment: @Gordory Я привел лишь как пример статическую функцию, но вы можете вызывать не статические функции, включая даже виртуальные функции.

Comment: @Gordory не статическая функция-член может использовать ещё неинициализированные члены класса, так что такой вариант не очень хорош.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow вызов виртуальной функции в конструкторе или инициализаторе конструктора опасный подход, в любом случае будет вызвана версия для текущего конструируемого класса. И эта функция вполне может быть "чистой" - получим "pure virtual call".

Comment: @alexolut Я предоставляю информацию о том, что допускается, а не о том, какая специфика того или иного вызова.

Comment: Несколько необычное заявление, учитывая насколько объёмно Вы обычно расписываете ответы.

Comment: @alexolut Мне задали конкретный вопрос, о том. может ли не статическая функция использоваться, и я дал конкретный ответ, что да, может, и даже виртуальные функции могут использоватьсят.