# Члены данных/переменные-члены класса в виде ссылок/указателей

Tags: c++, классы

StackOverflow!!! У меня возник вопрос по поводу одного примера из книги "C++.Практика многопоточного программирования".Автор реализует класс в котором переменные-члены(члены данных) используются в качестве ссылок(в других примерах,в качестве указателей).То есть:

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
class Secret
{
private:
  int *m_value;
  int &m_number;
public:
  Secret(int value = 1001, int number = 110);
  int GetSecret();
  void SetSecret(int value, int number);
};
Secret::Secret(int value = 1001, int number = 110)
{
  *m_value = value;
  m_number = number;

}
int Secret::GetSecret()
{
  return *m_value;
  return m_number;
}
void Secret::SetSecret(int value, int number)
{
  m_value = &value;//В этой строке явно что-то не так
  m_number = number;//В этой тоже.Неплохо было бы объяснить что не так.
}
int main()
{
  Secret secret1;
  
}
```

Я знаю,что код не очень,но все же я его быстро набросал чтобы дать хоть какую-нибудь ясность.

Главный вопрос:**"Можно ли создавать члены-данных класса в виде ссылок/указателей и для чего это надо???** Объясните пожалуйста!

**+мне кажется в конструкторе полная лабуда получится???**

Comment: "Можно ли создавать члены-данных класса в виде ссылок/указателей" Это бред какой-то. Сначала надо определится, что всётаки нужно получить.

Comment: чтобы сохранить указатель или ссылку в переменную класса нужно также как аргумент передавать указатель/ссылку . А не значение как у вас.

Comment: Никита Самоуков,есди честно то бред это ваш комментарий.Начните читать книгу представленную выше ,сами начнете задаваться такими вопросами.

Comment: Планета  может иметь  море, может не иметь, а может иметь несколько. Значит класс "Планета" логично может  содержит указатель на море. Но оно имеет одно "Ядро", и это ядро не может существовать, когда планеты не будет.  Логично оно содержит(может содержать) ссылку на ядро

Comment: Они  не *"используются в качестве ссылок"*, они имеют соответствующий тип - ссылку или указатель.

Comment: мне функция SetSecret тоже не нравится. сохранить адрес параметра функции...

Comment: [Двоеточие в определении конструктора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/468496), [Синтаксис инициализации const членов класса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/588056).

Comment: @AlexGlebe Уже много времени прошло ,и я снова не понимаю, можете объяснить почему если член-данных(`ссылка/указатель`) нужно в качестве параметра конструктора тоже   **именно** ссылку/указатель передавать?Это условие языка???Или...? Разве нельзя сделать что-то типа этого :`Secret::Secret(int  value , int number ) :
 m_value ( &value) ,m_number ( number)` .Или это не сработает??? Ответьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Передача аргументов в функцию происходит **копированием**. Если аргумент допустим `void f(int a)` а вызываете `int x=5;f(x+0);` то `x` это одно число, а `a == x+0` это другое (в другом месте памяти). И вы вторую копию как не исправляйте, первое число не будет меняться. А если аргумент это указатель, то произойдёт **копия** указателя, что не страшно. `void f(int * p);int x=6;f(&x);` Вы сможете менять переменную `x` и через указатель `&x` и через копию указателя `p`, что приведёт к изменению значения переменной `x` в любом случае.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Члены данных как указатель или ссылка нужна для удалённого управления данными. Если например, несколько объектов хранят указатель на общее число, то эти объекты могут удалённо менять данные.

Меняем конструктор, который просто указывает, с какими данными нужно связаться. И вызываем функцию объекта. Эта функция будет менять значения удалённо.

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
class Secret
{
private:
  int *m_value;
  int &m_number;
public:
  Secret(int * value , int & number );
  int GetSecret();
  void SetSecret(int value, int number);
};
Secret::Secret(int * value , int & number ) :
 m_value ( value) ,m_number ( number)
{
}
int Secret::GetSecret()
{
  return *m_value;
  return m_number;
}
void Secret::SetSecret(int value, int number)
{
  // в переменную по адресу даём новое значение
  * m_value = value; 
  // в переменную по внутренней ссылке даём новое значение
  m_number = number;
}
int main()
{
  int val = 0 ;
  int num = 1 ;
  cout <<"val="<<val<<" num="<<num<<endl;
  // назначаем в классе указатель и ссылку
  Secret secret1(&val,num);
  // функция меняет значения по указателю и ссылке
  secret1.SetSecret(2,3);
  cout <<"val="<<val<<" num="<<num<<endl;
}
```

Результат :

```
$ ./a.out 
val=0 num=1
val=2 num=3
```

Comment: Знаете,я долго разбирался с вашим кодом,так как не мог понять некоторые нюансы.Но все же один остался.В конструкторе адрес *указателя* _value_ присваивается *указателю* _m_value_ или??? А как с ссылкой _number_ на _m_number_???Кстати спасибо огромное за ответ!!!

Comment: Указатель `m_value = & val` - это адрес памяти, где содержится переменная `val`. А ссылка `m_number = num` - это переменная, где значение берётся из переменной `num`.

Comment: Сначала не врубился,даже завис,теперь все понял.Спасибо огромное за потраченное время и объяснение AlexGlebe!!!